# How to create a new column containing yes and no after number from existing column is divisible by 3 or not in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I want to create a new column in a pandas dataframe containing yes if a number from existing column for ex column sales is divisible by 3 and containing no if a number from column sales is not divisible by 3

Comment: You need to include sample data and example output

Answer (score 2):

```
your_data["divisible_by_3"] = your_data["sales"] % 3 == 0
```

It returns True if its divisible otherwise False